# How can I boot Mac OS X install DVD through GRUB on a Mac Mini

Tags: macos, ubuntu, installation, dvd, grub

I have a Mac Mini with Ubuntu Fiesty on it - but need to re-Mac it. My problem is that I can get it to recognise the install DVD. I've tried using the memdisk.bin / sbootmgr.dsk combo but can't seem to get it to work. Any ideas?

Edit: if it helps, running `grep cdrom /etc/fstab` I have identified the internal DVD-ROM drive as '/dev/scd0   /media/dcrom0  udf,iso9660, user,noauto,exec,utf8 0 0'

Can anyone translate this into into a GRUB (hdn,n) type designation?

Edit No 2: I have no downloaded a a working Live CD of Ubuntu 9.0.4, but with little success. I've tried using gparted to reformat the internal drive. I've tried 'mac' 'msdos' and 'ntfs' - with msdos I get no apparent partitions, but my assumption that this erases the boot block seems wrong.

I get a suspiciously unix-like error message on restart, it fails to recognise the OS X 10.6 dvd, won't respond to option-key to bring up Apple startup disk chooser, or the C-key to boot from the internal drive. As far as re-instating OS X, looks like I have a bricked mac-mini...

So, how to I NUKE the internal drive to ensure that there's no unix boot nonsense? or has the original Apple firmware somehow been destroyed?

Comment: Updated the solution in the below comments - i got a strong feeling this will get your EFI back.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried holding down the "Option" key or the "C" key while turning on the Mac?? There's no need to even get into GRUB.

EDIT : User had a bigger problem - his EFI is for some reason corrupted/non-existent. Suggested steps to restore EFI, or at least install rEFIt.

You would need to refer to this page for instructions on [how to use rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/doc/c1s1_install.html).

Once rEFIt is installed, you will gain back the option to boot using the OS X install DVD. Give it a whirl and let us know.

Comment: you mean you wiped out EFI from your Mac Mini? or for some reason your DVD is not recognized at the start?

Comment: I have no idea. This is an inherited Mac Mini. DVD certainly recognised within Ubuntu... but since option doesn't bring up standard OS X boot menu, and this is a new OS X 10.6 Install DVD that has worked on other Macs... I guess yes to both. Hence the grub query...

Comment: Dear me, that's messed up. Your question should be how to restore EFI actually (otherwise I highly suspect your OS X won't install too.) Edited my answer.

Comment: If  I could erase all partitions from the drive, surely I should be able to boot from the install CD? Almost tempted to stick a virgin drive in there and see what happens...

Comment: At this juncture, I have no idea what will happen. This is the first time I encountered an erased/corrupted EFI. Stick a virgin drive in, for all you know it might just work. You might want to reset the PRAM too (hold down Option+P+R when turning on the Mac Mini)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, it don't happen to be a PowerPC Mac Mini, and the disc you are trying to boot from is a Snow Leopard disc is it?

Comment: No, it's an Intel Mac Mini. And the reFIT instructions appear to assume that you already have a Mac up and running - or do you have a method for opening a .dmg file on Ubuntu? (Tried the usual dead-chicken waving - co-PR and trying to boot into open firmware..., but thanks for you efforts.)

Comment: No worries - it's things like this that keeps my brain cells alive.

Okay I have new developments on your issue - it would appear that your HFS+ partition is marked as "hidden" and "lvm" - that is your EFI partition, and it is now just a logical volume.

Comment: you would need to boot into linux again, and remove these two flags from that partition. FDISK is your friend here. Once you remove these two flags, your EFI should work again (as in becomes bootable).

Comment: A litte cryptic - how do I remove flags using FDISK - some pointers would be good...

Answer (score 0):

"Okay I have new developments on your issue - it would appear that your HFS+ partition is marked as "hidden" and "lvm" - that is your EFI partition, and it is now just a logical volume" ...
Hmm, that's quite a leap! Actually there are just two logical partitions - one of which is swap... so formatting the drive is probably the easiest option.